# 100% width or height for larger among them

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I set the biggest width and height without video cutting and page scrolling?

```
<style>
    video {
        width:  ?;
        height: ?;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details about what you need?

Comment: I updated the question, I need to set the biggest possible width and height to video element without page scrolling and video cutting.

Answer (score 2):

You could do media queries for portrait or landscape orientations

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation)

```
<style>
    @media all and (orientation: portrait) {
        video {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    }

    @media all and (orientation: landscape) {
        video {
            min-width: 100%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, this not changed anything.

Comment: Height/Width are weird attributes. If you want to force it to be a certain size try using min-height/min-width instead

Answer (score 2):

First lets find the ratio between height and width. For example 16 / 9 ration means that the width is 177.778% of the height or the height is 56.25% of the width. And this brings us to the following css:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { /** vmin = width **/
    .video {
        width: 100vmin; /** width is the 100% **/
        height: 56.25vmin; /** height is in relation to width **/
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { /** vmin = height, vmax = width **/
    .video {
        width: 100vmax; // width is the 100%
        height: 56.25vmax; // height is in relation to width
        max-width: 177.778vmin; // the maximum width however is constrained by the height
        max-height: 100vmin; // and the height can't go beyond the viewport height 
    }
}
```

This is a [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jgcgnpeu/1/) that displays the behavior - resize the bottom right pane. Note that yellow means landscape and red means portrait.

Comment: This just did 100% width and height, I don't want to scroll the page to see the full video size.

Comment: If you want the larger of them, you'll always have scroll in one direction or the other. If you want 100% of the smaller use vmin. If you want the exact size use vw and vh. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Sorry, my question is incorrect, I need max possible video width and height without page scrolling and without video size cutting.

Comment: And you want to keep aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes, that what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` to find the height and width of the display. Now find the aspect ratio or simply the ratio of these and compare it with the aspect ratio of your video. 
If your video's height/width is more than height/width of the device set width to be 100% else set height to be 100%.

```
deviceRatio = window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth;
videoRatio = //whatever it is 
if(deviceRatio>videoRatio){
    //set the video to have 100% width
}
else{
    //set the video to have 100% height
}
```